# Peace lily dying. Please help!

Tags: diagnosis

[image][image][image][image]

Help! Can someone tell me what's killing my peace lily? Iv had this plant for about 9 months. It seems like the Plant does well for about a week after I will trim all the dead leaves off and then it's back to looking like this. The leaves turn brown, get crispy and shrivel up. Some of then will even yellow. Some of them have brown spots, that look like they have been eaten out of them. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I thought maybe it was getting to much light so I moved it to a room where it gets hardly no light. That hasn't helped. Iv watered it less.... that hasn't helped. Iv misted the leaves....that hasn't helped. Iv trimmed the dead off....that hasn't helped. 
I'm afraid that it's dying and don't know why?

Comment: How often do you water, how much water do you give it when you water, and how do you decide it does or doesn't need watering? Do you empty the outer pot after watering? What's the purpose of the lip sticking out of the pot?

Comment: @Bamboo I think it's a self watering pot. :)

Comment: @Alina - I asked if it was self watering the first time this question was posted and was told it wasn't... but it looks like one to me too! If it was, that would go some way to explaining the problems with this plant.

Comment: I water it about once a week. I water the plant when it barely starts to wilt. I water it around the plant and in water it enough to wet down to the bottom of the soil but not to much where it flows out the bottom. If the water does happen to drain out the bottom, I will remove the the outter/bottom pot and drain the water from it. The lip at the bottom of the pot is a spot where I can add water to it if I want and the plant will suck the water up from the bottom. However, I DO NOT water the plant this way. I always water from the top.

Comment: . I keep the bottom pot attached to the top pot so that water & soil doesn't come out onto my carpet. It just attached to the main pit to catch water if there's a need. I just don't understand what is wrong with the plants. They do well for a few week and then look like this. I will trim all the dead off and they do well agian for a few weeks and then start looking like this. I use filtered water to water them. Should they be receiving alot of sunlight or not?

Answer (score 1):

Your watering regimen seems appropriate so I fear you should consider [*Phytophthora nicotianae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytophthora_nicotianae) (Black Shank). [cleaning off the roots and repotting the plant in fresh, healthy soil](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/peace-lily/diseases-spathiphyllum-tips-treating-peace-lily-diseases.htm) may help.

Another possibility is [*Cylindrocladium spathiphylli*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calonectria), a fungus that also rots roots. It is mentioned in a report by D.J. Norman: ["Control of Cylindrocladium Root Rot of Spathiphyllum with Fungicide Drenches"](http://mrec.ifas.ufl.edu/Foliage/Resrpts/rh_96_6.htm).

[Avoid direct sunlight](http://www.wikihow.com/Care-for-Peace-Lilies) - shady is fine.